# git redownload repository after poweroff

Tags: git, github

I had some power off during pulling from repository and it gets weird. It says I cant switch repository as:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
```

I think its some uncausal error so I just need git to redownload completly every file of repo. How to? Somethink like 'reclone' - without care of files structure as its wrong for sure.

Checkouting to other repository and then back didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have files which have not been added and committed, and would get overwritten because of a different version, it'll happen.

You may want to do a git stash on that first, then go about your things.

You may still get git merge errors if those files were modified in a way that they can't be merged by a regular diff/text merger. In those cases, you are better off resolving them yourself.

Comment: stash dont help... stash is based on some files tree info that is crashed. No way to just simply redownload it like I would do in '95?

Comment: What do you mean by re-download? If you are seeing some bad files which you don't want to keep, there's the git reset --hard command. Also if you've deleted/modified some files, you can always do a git checkout -- path-to-file ... Which of these methods didn't work for you? You could share more information, please. Also, please rephrase your question.

Comment: hard reset uses info of all changed files of working copy. As I've sad I cant rely on this becouse my git info files are crashed. Any 'logical' git function I know does not help.

Answer (score 0):

If the repository is fine, and you are just re-cloning then you can just delete your .git folder in your project. This tracks everything that is involved with git. Then you can just clone as normal:

```
git clone https://github.com/something/somewhere.git
```

But back up your .git folder elsewhere before you do this.